# Using one socket to both receiving and sending messages in Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, timeout, client

I have a python script, which already sends messages from time to time to peer using socket. I want to add a feature, that socket listens asynchronously for inbound messages and then reacts, for ex. processes content and resends a reply. Is it possible to do it using only one socket? I have to use one socket because my peer creates its socket on localhost:30000.

EDIT:

Here is some code of my tries I have done so far.

Run() method from the listening thread:

```
def run(self):
    print("Started listening to messages from peer...")
    while True:
        socketLock.acquire()
        try:
            self.listenToInboundMessages()
        finally:
            socketFlag.set()
            socketLock.notify()
            socketLock.release()

def listenToInboundMessages(self):
    clientsocket.settimeout(1)
    received = clientsocket.recv(BUFF)
    print(received)
```

Run() method for the thread which sends messages:

```
def run(self):
    print("Ready to send messages.")
    while True:
        print("Attempting to acquire lock...")
        socketLock.acquire()
        while not socketFlag.isAvailable():
            socketLock.wait
        print("Attempting to send message...")
        clientsocket.send("Message for per")
        socketLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I use `socketLock` condition variable and `socketFlag` class to coordinate both threads.

Comment: please provide your code whatever your have tried

Comment: Are you sending messages between two threads within the *same process?*

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can use the select class to filter a list of socket connections into 3 lists, sockets that are ready to ready, sockets that are ready to write, and sockets that have errors.

Here is a basic implementation for a p2p socket connection (not class based).

```
import socket, select, time

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("10.48.72.71", 8080))
s.listen(10)

connections = [s]

while True:
    time.sleep(.1)

    recv,write,err = select.select(connections,connections,connections)

    for socket in recv:
        if socket == s:
            client,address = socket.accept()
            connections.append(client)
        else:
            msg = socket.recv(4096).decode("UTF-8")
            print("Recieved message from a socket, message was: "+str(msg))

    for socket in write:
        socket.send(bytes("Hi", "UTF-8"))

    for socket in err:
        print("Error with a socket")
        socket.close()
        connections.remove(socket)
```

Comment: I suppose select works also on Linux? Can I use socket returned to `write` any time I would like to send an outbound message?